# Any idea how to modify regex to check for zipcode or address?

Tags: php, regex

The code below follows the rules defined in the regex.

1. If ID is all digits, then then insert a space after the first 2 digits.
2. If ID has a character after the first 2 digits and no other characters, then no changes.
3. If ID has digits and characters and the characters are GG anywhere in the digits, then insert 2 spaces before the GG.

The code I have below satisfies these rules.

These rules are intended to improve the current search functionality in production mode.

The problems we have ran into after implementing these rules are twofold.

1, users can search with ID, zipcode and address with the current production app and get results if their search params are valid.

After implementing these rules, the zipcode search and address searches no longer work.

For instance, as with ID, if a user searches with Id, the result outputted is ONLY the ID the user searched with. The user then clicks that ID.

Same with zip code and for the most part, address works that way depending on whether the user enter full address or a portion of the address in which case addresses matching the portion entered are displayed.

The zipcode and address don't work this new modified version in our dev server.

I would be eternally grateful for any assistance figuring out why code stopped working after the mode.

I came up with the regex but someone else wrote the query.

```
function format($matches)
{
    return $matches[1][0].(strlen($matches[2][0])>0?$matches[2][0]:" ").$matches[3][0].(strlen($matches[4][0])>0?"  ".$matches[4][0]:"");
}

// construct regular expression
$pattern
= '/'         // regex delimiter
. '('         // START of a capture group
. '\d{2}'     // exactly two digits
. ')'         // END of capture group
. '('         // START SECOND capture group
. '[\sND]?'     // letters "D" OR "N" in any order or number - This is optional
. ')'         // END SECOND capture group
. '('         // START THIRD capture group
. '\d*'       // any number of digits
. ')'         // END THIRD capture group
. '('         // START FOURTH capture group
. 'GG'        // the letters "GG" EXACTLY
. '[\d]*'     // any number of digits
. ')'         // END THIRD capture group
. '?'         // make the LAST capture group OPTIONAL
. '/'         // regex delimiter
;

// get current matche
preg_match_all($pattern, $_GET['id'], $matches);

// reformat the match
$str = format($matches);


// query
$tsql = "SELECT *
FROM searchtable AS ST
inner join CONTAINSTABLE(gSearch, Name, '\"$id*\"') AS GT
ON ST.GUID = GT.[KEY]
WHERE GT.RANK > 0
ORDER BY list, Name, GT.RANK DESC";
```

If it helps, these are the changes I made after the regex was written.

I changed this that current works in prod:

```
$id= $_GET["id"];
```

to this:

```
// get current matche
preg_match_all($pattern, $_GET['id'], $matches);

// reformat the match
$str = format($matches);
```

I didn't mess with the query so I think my issue has to do with the regex.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Address and Zipcode does not have any standard format. You can not valiate by regex.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it would be easier, smarter and more maintainable to do it in steps:

```
$search = $_GET['id'];

if (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $search)) { // Only digits
    $search = substr($search, 0, 2).' '.substr($search, 2);
} else if (preg_match('/^\d+?GG\d+?$/', $search)) { // 'GG' between digits
    $search = str_replace('GG', '  GG', $search);
}

// query
$tsql = "SELECT *
FROM searchtable AS ST
inner join CONTAINSTABLE(gSearch, Name, '\"$search*\"') AS GT
ON ST.GUID = GT.[KEY]
WHERE GT.RANK > 0
ORDER BY list, Name, GT.RANK DESC";
```

Comment: thank you very much for your kindness. I am not able to test right now since access to vpn is down but does your code mean that I no longer need the regular expression construct above or is this a separate validation?

Comment: Ye, forget the regexp you had. You prolly still need to call format() though.

Comment: sorry a bit confused as to how to integrate yours with mine.

Comment: edited with full code; just figured why your old code wasn't working, though. On original code, the search value was placed on `$id`, but on the new code, it's placed on `$str` and you didn't change the query to reflect that.

Comment: thanks again. I get the changes you made but I am still confused how to integrate your code with the regex I have already. That's where my confusion is; not on the query.

Also, can you please be more specific about what you said about original being placed on $id versus $str?

thanks again for your kindness

Comment: Take all the code you put here and replace with all the code I posted. About `$id` vs. ´$str´, check your `$tsql = ...` old line. You had `$id` in the middle of it, but `$id` no longer existed, it was replaced with ´$str`.

Comment: sorry @Raphael, it didn't work. it is not even displaying any search results.